# C++ remove quote from char type

Tags: c++, quote

Need test variable remove quotes. How to?

```
char test[] = "\"C:\\hello\"";

if(test[0] = '"')
{
 // test variable 0 index to blank
}
```

Comment: You can use a `std::string` which has convenient member functions for this type of operation.

Comment: Btw, test is array, not a single variable

Comment: To delete a character in an array you will need to move the remaining characters to where the key character is .  There is no operation to delete slots in an array and have the array automatically resize.  You may want to review `std::vector<char>` or use `std::string`.

Comment: Just gotta say, `if (test[0] = '"')` will assign `"` to `test[0]`, then evaluate to true.  At the very least, you may want to check `if (test[0] == '"')`, with double equals signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, call the [PathUnquoteSpaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773763(v=vs.85).aspx) function in the Windows API.

```
PathUnquoteSpaces(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove a character in a character array, you will need to overwrite the slot with the remaining text.

Original:

```
+---+---+---+----+   
| " | C | : | \0 |  
+---+---+---+----+   
      |  
  +---+  Copy from original.
  |
  V  
+---+---+----+----+   
| C | : | \0 | \0 |  
+---+---+----+----+
```

See `memmove` for copying when destinations overlap.

An easier solution is to use `std::string` for all your multi-character texts and its methods.